# How to find adjacent polygons in leaflet

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, turfjs

I'm using leaflet and i want to found all layer adjacent to a selected layer. For example i have the following situation:

[image]

I would like to get adj1,adj2 and adj3 layers, I tried with intersection and contains method of leaflet but its doesn't work. Any suggestion about this?

**Update 1**

```
 layer.on('click', function(e) { 
  let isNeighboorAce = acesSelected.some(ace => { ace.poligon.getBounds().intersects(poligon.getBounds()) || ace.poligon.getBounds().contains(poligon.getBounds())});
  if(isNeighboorAce) {
    //Ci sono ace contigue quindi posso aggiungere
    acesSelected.push(aceSelected);
    layer.setStyle({fillOpacity: 0.4 , color: '#004691', weight: 3});
  } 
}
```

});

Comment: Where is the code you've written to try and solve this problem?

Comment: I updated my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know if two polygons are adjacent, you can call the [getlatlngs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#polygon-getlatlngs) method to get a list of points coordinates for each of them. Then use the [distance](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#crs-distance) method for each pair of points. If for any pair, the distance is 0, the 2 polygons are adjacent.

Edit : 
Actually it is better to use [pointToSegmentDistance](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#lineutil-pointtosegmentdistance). Because 2 adjacent polygons do not necessarily share a point. In that case, you loop through all the segments of the first polygon (using getlatlngs) and compute the distance to all the coordinates of the second polygon.

Comment: Sorry, can you get me some snippet of code about this? thanks

Comment: Create a little example on jsfiddle and I will try

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be dealing with polygons for administrative boundaries, I would prefer to use [TopoJSON](https://github.com/topojson/topojson) to create a topological representation of the data. (Since you have a reasonable guarantee that the boundaries will share points with the same coordinates).

There are a lot of approaches to this. I would suggest going for preparing adjacency data *once* (using topojson, extract information of the IDs of polygons at each side of each edge, create a data structure relating the IDs of each polygon with an array of IDs of all adjacent), and loading two pieces of data in Leaflet (the current GeoJSON data and then the adjacency data).